# Nginx : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

While I was configuring keyrock IDM with Nginx, I was raised with the following error.This was viewed on google chrome developer tools console.

```
handle_get_members.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.success (handle_get_members.js:9)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

This was raised when I was using one of the functionality(to list the members) on keyrock.

My nginx conf file look like this as below:

```
 location /key/
        {
             proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
             proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
             proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             rewrite ^/key(/.*)$  $1 break;
             proxy_pass           https://Keyrock-Host:Keyrock-Port;
             proxy_redirect / /key/;
             sub_filter '="/' '="/key/';
             sub_filter '= "/' '= "/key/';
             sub_filter '=\'/' '=\'/key/';
             sub_filter_once off;
        }
    location /idm/
        {
             proxy_pass   https://Keyrock-Host:Keyrock-Port/idm/;
        }
    location /img/
        {
             proxy_pass   https://Keyrock-Host:Keyrock-Port/img/;
        }
```

Below is the snapshot of the error I am facing. If anyone has faced any similar kind of issue.?

---

**Update 1:** After the comment

The url for list of members is : `/idm/organizations/589b97efe-d03c-122f-c522-3e557fa24a37`

Whereas accessing it with nginx : `/key/idm/organization/organizations`

This is because The Code in the Backend in Fiware Keyrock is :

```
var url = '/idm/organizations/'+window.location.pathname.split('/')[3]
```

Thus the value taken is [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0oUz.png) from variable, which is organization instead of its id in nginx and thus is not able to fetch.

[image]

---

**Update 2:**

The files after accessing it with nginx. The value of url is as shown below:

[image]

---

Update 3:

In the network console of google chrome dev tools while previewing the profile section of admin user, I am shown the following

[image]

Comment: the problem is in line 9 of `handle_get_members.js` and line 9 of `handle_get_applications.js` - check what these files look like in the browser - you're probably breaking something, but without being able to see either of these files, the answer is a coconut

Comment: Line 9 for handle_get_members.js https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/blob/7.5.1/public/javascripts/organizations/handle_get_members.js#L9. While for https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/blob/7.5.1/public/javascripts/organizations/handle_get_applications.js#L9.

Comment: How about putting the relevant code in the question

Comment: Also. What do those files look like **after** your nginx messes them up

Comment: in `update 2` modify line-9 to `if(data && data.users && data.users.length > 0)`

Comment: Hi @VikashSingh, I am still unable to run it using nginx. It is still not displaying the members. :(

Comment: Hi @VikashSingh , any other setting that can be done?

Comment: Hi @Jaromanda , any other setting that can be done?

Comment: clearly `data.users` is undefined on line 9 - I have no idea why, because you've posted a picture of code, which is about as useful as insect screens on a submarine

Comment: @JaromandaX please let me know what else can I post so as to find the reason of issue? I am happy to help.

Comment: I think I've said  twice ... the code as it appears in the browser